# Protractor - Identify elements using their child

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

Im trying to change the input element's text, but i need to identify it. The element doesnt have an id or something else. Also the same object appears multiple times in the code, so i can't grab it by the model etc.

But another "childobject" is in the same parent object, which has an id.
Sample code of my situation:

```
<field ... class="testClass">
  <field ... class="smallTestClass">
    <div class="ng.scope">
    <input ng-model= "vm.ItemInfos[xIndex][yIndex]" >
    </div>
  </field>
  <label ... id="21"/>
<field>
```

I want to change the value of "input" but cant get the element.

```
var child = parent.element(by.xpath('//input[@ng-model= "vm.ItemInfos[xIndex][yIndex]"');
```

It just takes the first with this syntax aswell, not looking at the parent.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element(by.xpath('//field[@class="testClass"][label[@id="21"]]//input'))`

or

`element(by.xpath('//field[@class="testClass"][label[@id="21"]]')).element(by.css('input'))`